# How can i get updated entity from objectdateContext.SaveChanges() method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I am updating data in the table and then on its update inserting date in other history table with has same fields as first table.

my code is:

```
 public void SaveChanges()
    {
      objectdateContext.SaveChanges();

      saveInHistoryTable(); // here how i can pass the current entity.
    }

 public void saveInHistoryTable(FirstTable f)
 {
    SecondTable s = new SecondTable();
    s.id = f.id;
    s.Name = f.Name;
    objectdateContext.Insert(s);
}
```

Please guide me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`saveInHistoryTable(); // here how i can pass the current entity.`

The entity is long gone by this point. You should be calling this method and passing in the entity after the changes are made in whatever method that occurs at.

You should separate out these concerns into different methods. Honestly, `SaveChanges()` should not include making a backup of a "current entity". Moreover, how do you know that only one entity was changed? If it were an object graph that were changed, then it would be impossible to only pass in one object and have the whole graph backed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the SaveChanges() in your context, and then for each object in the ChangeTracker do your save.

Here's an example I've used before (this is for a DbContext, if you have an object context it will differ slightly):

```
  public override int SaveChanges()
  {
     if( ChangeTracker.Entries().Any( e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged ) )
     {
        //insert the entry into the History table
     }

     return base.SaveChanges();
  }
```

Comment: This solution seems interesting, i, thinking about how it works with an object graph, same question of @Travis J in the response below, but the ChangeTracker.Entries() could solve this problem. Will test it.